# setTimeout works for every one second but not every 60 seconds

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I need to update the timer number every 60 seconds. If I set the timeout to 1000 milliseconds everything works fine except the number updates every one second. If I set 60000 milliseconds, the timer number does not update.

```
    //Power off on low battery timer
    var resetC=30; //time in minutes to reset timer to.
    var c=resetC;
    var t;
    var timer_is_on=0;
    function timedCount() {
        $('#timer').html(c);
        if(c>=1){
            c=c-1;
            t=setTimeout(function(){timedCount()},60000);
        }else{
            $('#batInfo').html('<H4>Powering off device.</H4>');
            window.setTimeout(function(){device.powerOff()},4000);
            stopCount();
        }
    }
    function doTimer(){
        if (!timer_is_on){
          timer_is_on=1;
          timedCount();
        }
    }

    function stopCount()
    {
        clearTimeout(t);
        timer_is_on=0;
        c=resetC;
    }
```

Comment: Don't. Use the `Date` object for proper timings.

Comment: What starts the timer cycle?  What calls "doTimer"?

Comment: The only reason I can find for the described behavior on this code is that something, somewhere else in you code is either calling stopCount before the 60 seconds have elapsed or setting **c** to 0. You say that when you set the timeout to 1000 ms, the updates occur every second, but have you counted 60 or more updates?

Answer (score -2):

What you maybe looking for is `setInterval`

Here is how I would write it with `setInterval`: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x7dwH/2/)

Its very similar to what you have written.